# sql split an integer to numbers

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have an input like this `4541` or `45` or `124`

and I would like to split the input to its numbers like this:

if the input is `1235`, I want to take `1` , `2`, `3`, `5`

I tried to search on google but everything I found is spliting numbers from float or change string to numbers.

could you help please?

Comment: Is the number of digits always 4??

Comment: @apomene no not always `4`, I gave you examples, it can be any length

Comment: Is Number always Positive?

Comment: what is the purpose of this and how do you plan to use the result? do you just need a comma separated list in a single result? or would results in separate columns or rows be better? also, would you prefer it in a stored proc/function or just a straight sql solution

Comment: @MeysamTolouee yes it is

Comment: @Tanner I would prefer SP, I need to use it later by chaning the numbers ( that I got ) to strings, I can do that myself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Method 1:**

Try this

**Function:**

```
IF EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sys.objects WHERE object_id = OBJECT_ID(N'[dbo].[SplitIntoIndividualLetters]') AND type in (N'FN', N'IF', N'TF', N'FS', N'FT')) 
DROP FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIntoIndividualLetters] 
GO 
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[SplitIntoIndividualLetters](@Str varchar(8000)) 
Returns @Lettertable TABLE (letters varchar(8000)) 
AS 
Begin 
;With NumCte As 
( 
Select Number = 1 Union All 
Select Number +1 From NumCte 
Where Number < 1000 
) 
Insert Into @Lettertable(letters) 
Select Substring(@str,Number,1) 
From NumCte 
where Number Between 1 And Len(@str) 
Option (Maxrecursion 0) 
Return 
End
```

How to use:

```
Declare @str Varchar(50) = '12345' 
DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + letters
FROM dbo.SplitIntoIndividualLetters(@str) 
SELECT @listStr
```

**Output:**

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

**Method 2 :**

I have came up with [Donal](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24240781/2118383) Solution:

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50),@Inc INT,@len INT,@char VARCHAR(50)

SET @str = '12345'
SET @Inc = 1
SET @len = LEN(@str)

WHILE @Inc<= @len
BEGIN
  SET @char = COALESCE(@char+',' ,'') + SUBSTRING(@str, @Inc, 1)  
  SET @Inc=@Inc+1
END

SELECT @char
```

Output:

```
1,2,3,4,5
```

**Number to Word**

```
CREATE FUNCTION fnIntegerToWords(@Number as BIGINT) 
    RETURNS VARCHAR(1024)
AS

BEGIN
      DECLARE @Below20 TABLE (ID int identity(0,1), Word varchar(32))
      DECLARE @Below100 TABLE (ID int identity(2,1), Word varchar(32))
      INSERT @Below20 (Word) VALUES 
                        ( 'Zero'), ('One'),( 'Two' ), ( 'Three'),
                        ( 'Four' ), ( 'Five' ), ( 'Six' ), ( 'Seven' ),
                        ( 'Eight'), ( 'Nine'), ( 'Ten'), ( 'Eleven' ),
                        ( 'Twelve' ), ( 'Thirteen' ), ( 'Fourteen'),
                        ( 'Fifteen' ), ('Sixteen' ), ( 'Seventeen'),
                        ('Eighteen' ), ( 'Nineteen' ) 

       INSERT @Below100 VALUES ('Twenty'), ('Thirty'),('Forty'), ('Fifty'),
                               ('Sixty'), ('Seventy'), ('Eighty'), ('Ninety')

    declare @belowHundred as varchar(126) 

    if @Number > 99 begin
        select @belowHundred = dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number % 100)
    end

    DECLARE @English varchar(1024) = 

    (

      SELECT Case 
        WHEN @Number = 0 THEN  ''

        WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1 AND 19 
          THEN (SELECT Word FROM @Below20 WHERE ID=@Number)

       WHEN @Number BETWEEN 20 AND 99   
         THEN  (SELECT Word FROM @Below100 WHERE ID=@Number/10)+ '-' +
               dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number % 10) 

       WHEN @Number BETWEEN 100 AND 999   
         THEN  (dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number / 100)) +' Hundred '+
             Case WHEN @belowHundred <> '' THEN 'and ' + @belowHundred else @belowHundred end 

       WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000 AND 999999   
         THEN  (dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number / 1000))+' Thousand '+
             dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number % 1000)  

       WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000 AND 999999999   
         THEN  (dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number / 1000000))+' Million '+
             dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number % 1000000) 

       WHEN @Number BETWEEN 1000000000 AND 999999999999   
         THEN  (dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number / 1000000000))+' Billion '+
             dbo.fnIntegerToWords( @Number % 1000000000) 

            ELSE ' INVALID INPUT' END
    )

    SELECT @English = RTRIM(@English)

    SELECT @English = RTRIM(LEFT(@English,len(@English)-1))
        WHERE RIGHT(@English,1)='-'

    RETURN (@English)

END
```

**Usage:**

```
SELECT dbo.fnIntegerToWords(5) As Word


    Word
    Five
```

**To get the answer in comma separated list**

Try this

```
Declare @str Varchar(50) = '12345' 

DECLARE @listStr VARCHAR(MAX)
SELECT @listStr = COALESCE(@listStr+',' ,'') + dbo.fnIntegerToWords(letters)
FROM dbo.SplitIntoIndividualLetters(@str) 
SELECT @listStr
```

---

*Output:*

```
One,Two,Three,Four,Five
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I am trying the answer above, then i will try your answer. many thans

Comment: in your second method, is there a way please instead of returning `1,2,3,4` to return `one two three four`? I can do that myself, I just need you please to tell me how to take the separate number inside your `while`

Comment: yes exactly, but I don't want you to feel the paint of it, i just want you (if you please) to tell me how to get the separate number inside your while statement, for example `1` or `2` and them I will change it to text

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli For that you have to use recursive algorithm. I'll update that in my answer but you have to simplify it get answer..

Comment: sorry but what do you mean by `simplify it get answer` ?

Comment: to get the answer in Comma separated list like `one,two,..`

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Hey wait I'll update the exact answer

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli Yes i've updated. You have to use two functions to get the answer

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55694/discussion-between-vignesh-kumar-and-marco-dinatsoli).

Comment: why do you have `fourteen`, `fifteen`... ? I though it would be simpiler, your last function in the while statment, just check the letter, if `1`, add `one` to the result, and so one. right?

Comment: @MarcoDinatsoli yes you are right but it is full fledged function to convert number to word. it may help to othres

Comment: I edited the question and added the code in your first method and I showed you the result, It is exactly your code, the problem is that there is  `1` in the first of the result, could you check please

Answer (score 1):

You need to treat it as a string. Then you can use SUBSTRING to get each character.

```
DECLARE @str VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @i INT
DECLARE @len INT
DECLARE @char VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @result VARCHAR(50)

SET @str = '1235'
SET @i = 1
SET @len = LEN(@str)

WHILE @i<= @len
BEGIN
  SET @char = SUBSTRING(@str, @i, 1)
  @result = @char + ", "
  SET @i=@i+1
END
```

Comment: let me test it, but how did you change the interger to string ?

Comment: you just surround it with quotes, "" or ''.

Comment: I got these errores `Must declare the scalar variable "@string".` and `Must declare the scalar variable "@char".`

Comment: I have added the declarations above

Comment: ah yes, it is there now.

Comment: by `@string` you mean `@str` ?

Comment: when I executed your code on a stored procedure, I can't see the output, maybe because you `print`, could you just add ever `@char` to a varaible so we can return that variable at the end of the `while` please?

Comment: surely you are able to do this yourself?

Comment: +1 to you , many thanks, I am still trying it, it seems i have done something wrong, because it is go in infinity while

Answer (score 0):

no need to declare so much variable as others did, its simple .this work for me  : try it

```
declare @intvalue int
declare @incremnt int
 declare @data varchar(20)
set @intvalue = 1234
 set @data = CAST(@intvalue as varchar(10))
 set @incremnt = 1
 while(LEN(@data) >= @incremnt)
begin
 select SUBSTRING(@data,@incremnt,1)
set @incremnt = @incremnt + 1
 end
```